# Wanted to pass data from service to component in angular

Tags: angular, angular10

I am passing data from "uploadProgressbar" i am getting that data in console but wasn't able to get data in HTML file this code is in negotitation.service.ts and wants this data in card-detail.component.html

negotitation.service.ts

```
bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
  var uploaded = Math.round(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
  console.log(`File uploaded: ${uploaded}%`);
  this.uploadProgressbar = uploaded;
  console.log(this.uploadProgressbar);
}).send(function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    return;
  }
  var fileUrl = data.Location;
  console.log('File URL:', fileUrl);
  alert('File is uploaded successfully!');
})
```

card-detail.component.html

```
<div class="upload-percentage">
   <p>{{negoService.uploadProgressbar}} %</p>
</div>
```

card-detail.component.ts

```
constructor(private negoService: NegotiationService) { }
```

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/passing-data-from-service-to-component/. And, did you check the values of negoService when the component is loaded? It could be possible that your component loads first and then the values is updating in your service.

Comment: Have you tried creating a local property inside the component (`card-detail.component.ts`) and using the service method to store the data in that variable within the component to then use it in your template?